# how to make NGINX read static files directory when proxy passing

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location /assets {
                root /var/www/frappe/sites/assets;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

}
```

I want the /assets directory to be handled by NGINX while everything else handled by the python server running on 8000. However, I still get 404 on assets directory.

What am I doing wrong? The assets directory is readable by www-data.

Comment: Share an error.log please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get *all* 404s on requests to resources under `/assets`?  I suspect you may want to change `root` to `alias` in `location /assets`, because `root` appends the entire request path to the directory specified, which means nginx is looking for `/var/www/frappe/sites/assets/assets/site.css`, for instance.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) instead of `root`.  You don't even need `try_files`?

```
        location /assets/ {
                alias /var/www/frappe/sites/assets/;
        }
```